# Object rotation not behaving as expected

Tags: modeling, objects

I am having problems with the default rotation configuration in Blender 4.0

This is the object before I rotate it. It's lined up like it should be.
[image: Before rotating]

What I'd expect it to do is stay in the same position, but it doesn't. I need it to be aligned with the cylinder on the left, but it doesn't align.

[image: After rotating]

Comment: Hi :). Objects pivot around their origin point (the orange dot). Make sure it's in the center, or use a 3D cursor as pivot point.

Comment: You can also select the object, press G to grab and B to set a snapping point and align it to the cylinder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use Grab <kbd>G</kbd> on the object that was unaligned

[image: Grabbed unaligned object]

Then I pressed <kbd>B</kbd> to set a snapping point and set that on a vertex on the unaligned side.

[image: Grabbed object with snap point set on a vertex on the unaligned side.]

I could then use the mouse cursor to get the object correctly aligned.

[image: Grabbed object which is now aligned.]

After that I pressed <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd>  to confirm. It was now aligned.

[image: Aligned object]